# LPC2378FBD144 Arm7 hex file

Tags: decompilation, arm, hexrays, ida-plugin

I have binary file for the LPC2378FBD144 processor ineed to reverse engineer it using IDA V7.3
im little confused about memory organization values i should put in the memory organization thank you for your help :)
here the data sheet for the processor
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC2377_78.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARM7 cores use classic architecture with the exception vectors at the start of the binary (usually mapped at 0), so you can start with the defaults, start disassembling and if the addresses look wrong, rebase the image afterwards.